# Jquery - Get parent id (parent must have a special Classname)

Tags: jquery

i have the "c_500" id and i need the id from next parent with the classname "pp".

i search something like ...

```
$('#c_500').getNextParentWithClass('pp');
```

html

```
 <div id="d_548" class="pp">

    <div class="class_ft">

      Blub<hr />
      <div id="here">content</div>
      <div id="c_500">content</div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) with a [`.class` selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to get the element, then just grab the ID, like this:

```
$('#c_500').closest('.pp').attr('id');
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/M6t62/), [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is the same behavior as [`.parents('pp:first')`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/), walking up the parents until it finds the first one that matches the selector.

Comment: How do you get a jsFiddle with your name in the url?

Comment: @Ender - When you're logged in with your user account the URLs are created that way,  jsFiddle's doing to beta *very* soon, you'll be able to create an account via their UI once that happens.